# How to compute the gradient of a multidimensional array using numpy's fast Fourier transform

Tags: python, numpy, fft, derivative

I wrote this short and simple python method the other day

```
def dFFT_1D(f):
    k = 2*np.pi * np.fft.fftfreq(f.shape[0])
    return np.fft.ifft(1j*k * np.fft.fft(f)).real
```

which takes a one-dimensional array containing samples of a scalar function (step size is taken as unity) as input argument and returns the derivative using numpy's fast Fourier transform.

My goal is to generalize this method; so that it will take a multidimensional array and return the gradient/derivative along any of its axis.

```
def dFFT(f, axis):
    k = 2*np.pi * np.fft.fftfreq(f.shape[axis])
    return np.fft.ifftn( 1j*k * np.fft.fftn(f) ).real
```

for the sake of simplicity, let us take f to be two-dimensional array with shape (m,n) and say I wish to compute its derivative along its first axis (i.e. axis=0) using the above method. Then, my problem simply is that k has shape (m,) and therefor can't be broadcasted together with a (m,n) array. I have so far been able to come up with to different attempts at resolving this. My first attempt is simply to expand the dimension of k by

```
k = np.expand_dims(k, axis).T
```

which ensure that k has shape (n,1). My second attempt is to begin by swapping the axis of f

```
f = np.swapaxes(f, 0, axis)
```

However, both of these approaches doesn't seem elegant (as in efficiency and readability). I am also afraid that they don't really extend beyond the two-dimensionally case. I have tried reaching for a solution online, so far unsuccessfully.

Cheers!.

Comment: There are various ways of making a (m,) to (m,1), each basically equivalent in effect and efficiency.  `x[:,None]` is simplest (to an experienced numpy user).  `np.expend_dims(x, 1)`.  Or `reshape(-1,1)` etc.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do

```
1j * k[:, None] * np.fft.fftn(f)
```

to line up dimensions.